# .htaccess rewrite condigion for filematch if directory doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, json, .htaccess, http-status-code-204

i'm getting a little bit frustrated, so any help would be appreciated. Is it possible to catch a 404/directory not found, combined with a FilesMatch-block in .htaccess?

I created the following .htacces in order to rewrite non existing .json-files to a 204 No Content (preventing errors when using `$.getJSON`):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=204]

</FilesMatch>
```

I tested some things with the following files/directories-structure:

```
httpdocs
 - a
  - a.json
 - b
```

The .htaccess works when I request a non-existing configuration-file (`b/b.json`), but when I try to load a configuration-file of a non-existing directory  (`c/c.json`), a 404 statusCode will be returned instead of the desired 204.

Requesting `a/a.json` gives httpStatusCode 200 (Found, which is correct)

Requesting `b/b.json` gives httpStatusCode 204 (No content, also correct, handled by the .htaccess)

Requesting `c/c.json` gives httpStatusCode 404 (Not Found)

I want request c to return a 204 No Content as well. I've tried some thing like catching the directory from the request using `<FilesMatch .*\/(.*)\.(json)$>` and using the `$1` for the -d instead of the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`, but this doesn't work.

I also tried to catch the 404-error using the ErrorDocument, only for .json-files, but this doesn't seam to work. The redirect won't work and a 404 statusCode will be returned.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">

    ErrorDocument 404 /204.php

</FilesMatch>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas how to catch this?

Comment: Why use `FilesMatch` at all, just specify what URL format you want to match directly in the RewriteRule.

Comment: Remove `FilesMatch`, make the rule `RewriteRule \.json$ - [R=204]` instead, and you should be good.

Comment: Ah, nice. Don't know exactly why I was stuck to using FilesMatch, but removing it solves everything, thanks a lot @CBroe!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use `FilesMatch` here, you can simply limit what URLs this applies to directly in the RweriteRule itself.

```
RewriteRule \.json$ - [R=204]
```